# Add OTF Fonts to Webpage

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm trying to make a website with github pages and I would like to include an otf font. I can't get it to work correctly and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

I've done some research and I've found that I need to use @font-face but I can't figure out exactly how it's supposed to work. In most of the other solutions I have found I see people are using google to host their font or something like that but I would prefer to keep the font hosted on my github pages site. So far I have downloaded the otf font and added it to my sites repository and I attempted to follow some other guides with no luck.

At the moment my repository for the site contains the font file and the index.html file.

Here is my css for the font face:

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: MagnoliaScript;
   src: url("magnolia-script.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

And here I am trying to assign the font I have added to a header:

```html
<h1 face=MagnoliaScript>text</h1>
```

I followed what I was able to find online but I must be missing something because the font just stays the same.

Comment: I'm not certain what caused it, but I too have experienced problems with some `.OTF` fonts not displaying in the past. Try getting the font from a different resource (in case the file you got was corrupted), and as a last resort. you could always try using an online `OTF to TTF` converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here please try replacing this snippet

`<h1 face=MagnoliaScript>text</h1>`

with this one here :

`<h1 style="font-family:MagnoliaScript;">text</h1>`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You simply just add another @font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFont;
    src: url('CustomFont.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFont2;
    src: url('CustomFont2.otf');
}
```